# Running some code on a certain iteration in a loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a loop in my java program and I want to run some test code every say 10th iteration in the loop. How do I do this ???

Comment: Is going to be hard to help you if you dont provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)...

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? What's stopping you from using a counter variable?

Answer (score 3):

Use something like `if (i % 10 == 0)` where `i` is your loop counter. `%` is the *remainder operator*.

If `i` starts from `0` then the condition is `true` on the first iteration. If you want to start `i` from `0` but don't want the condition to be `true` until the 10<sup>th</sup> trial, then use `if (i % 10 == 9)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%` operator with `10` and your counter. See below for example.

```
for(int i=0;i<=100;i++){
    if(i>0&&i%10==0){
        System.out.println(i);//replace this with your code.
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `if(i>0&&i%10==0){` introduces a long interval at the beginning. You might want to clarify that.